# Streamreading text files

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code that is supposed to streamread this text file:

```
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1
1.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.1.1
1.1.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.1.1
1.1.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.1.1.1
1.1.1.1.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.1.1.1
1.1.1.1.2.2.2.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1.1.1.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
```

Everything is going fine, kinda of. My purpose was to rummage through all the characters one by one, then after that's done start on a new line. This is where my little problem occurs, which I've been trying to fix all night.

It reads the first line nicely, but then it doesn't read the second line...

Here is the code:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Text\TextFile.txt"); 

int loadX = 0;
int loadY = 0;
string line;

while (true)
{
    if (loadX <= 12)
    {
        loadX++;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            string[] entries = line.Split('.');
            System.Console.Write(entries[loadX]);
            loadY++;
        }
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.Write($" Finished {loadX}");
    loadX = 0;
}
```

Comment: I know you are tired, but you haven't asked a question

Comment: `while (true)`?? why?

Comment: There is all sorts of wrong here

Comment: the question was "It won't read the second line", or at least go through another line (EDIT: the while(true) was supposed to loop through the lines, i'm not sure please help

Comment: What is your end goal here?  The code makes no sense

Comment: It reads all lines, but only outputs the first number in each line... that's probably why you think it only does one line

Comment: Why don't you just read the entire file into a string directly and then work on the string? It won't be as efficient but for a small file it won' t matter

Comment: You might want to describe the format of your input. Are the `.` characters delimiters? Are the numbers in between restricted to a certain range? etc…

Comment: The problem is your use of `loadX` as an index. As it increments on each loop you are outputting the `loadX`th element of the array. As all elements on a line are the same it looks as if it is only he first character.

Comment: My end goal was to get the position of each line I guess, then use that position X and Y to a new object. 

Yes I know it reads the first number of each line. What I'm aiming for is to read the second bunch of numbers, but that wouldn't happen for some reason...

Comment: "My end goal was to get the position of each line" -- What does that _mean_?

Comment: Position of each line as in, how do I put it... Like, a certain position of where the streamreader is I guess. Which line it is on and the the position in the line?? Like an X and Y axis.

Comment: @MoonJaspers I just posted an answer that is much simpler then your accepted answer.  In case it's of use to you

Comment: @maccettura I will look into it! Many cheers guys! Your help is much appreciated, and I will again look into it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are mistaken to think it is reading the first line. In fact, your current code reads the first value of each line. Due to your input this just happens to be a similar output to what the first line would be, which has lead to your confusion.

Your main loop should be looping through each line, then you can process the line and loop through each value. Which you can then use however you want.

Here is an example:

```
using(System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Text\TextFile.txt"))
{
    int loadX = 0;
    int loadY = 0;
    string line;

    // Loop through each line as you read it.
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Split the line to get an array of values.
        string[] entries = line.Split('.');

        // Loop through each value and process.
        for(int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
        {
            string entry = entries[i];

            // TODO: Do something with entry.

            loadY++;
        }

        loadX++;
    }
}
```

Obviously in this example `loadX` and `loadY` are not being used, but this demonstrates how to correctly increment them so you can use them as needed.

TIP: When using a `SteamReader` you should ensure you dispose of it correctly, this is best done by including it in a `using` block.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it out, this seems more cleaner too!

Comment: I'd also like to ask where the y comes from? Is it loadY?

Comment: @MoonJaspers: Sorry, typo. It should be `i` from the loop. Fixed now

Comment: Cheers! I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop and StremReader seems so silly when you have easier and more readable ways of handling this.

You can easily simplify your code by doing `File.ReadAllLines()`

```
//lines will be a string array
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Text\TextFile.txt");
for(int x = 0; x < lines .Length; x++)
{
    var cols = lines [x].Split('.');
    for(int y = 0; y < cols.Length; x++)
    {
        //Here you have access to the value, and the x and y position
        Console.WriteLine("x: {0}, y: {1} value: {2}", x, y, cols[y]);
    }   
}
```

Demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TphyVy)

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Text\TextFile.txt");
var points = lines.SelectMany((l, x) => l.Split('.').Select((s, y) => new {X = x, Y = y, Value = s}));
foreach (var point in points)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"({point.X}, {point.Y})={point.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go through every number in this file with X and Y then this is an example how you can do so:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Text\TextFile.txt");

for(int indexY = 0; indexY < lines.Length; indexY++){
    string[] lineEntries = lines[indexY].Split('.');

    for(int indexX = 0; indexX < lineEntries; indexX++){
        // here you have one number by accessing
        // it with lineEntries[indexX]
        Console.Write(lineEntries[indexX]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```